# How to find COM interface definition for given interface GUID?

Tags: com

I have a COM interface GUID but I don't know that interface definition. I don't know what methods it has, what parameters they have and so on. How can I obtain such information? Is it possible in general?

---

Practical problem is obtaining interface definition for few COM interfaces defined in `actxprxy.dll`. For example `IFileDialogPrivate` (`{AC92FFC5-F0E9-455A-906B-4A83E74A803B}`). (Obviously the interface is not documented and the name does suggest there is a reason for that.) I tried to use `OLE/COM Object Viewer` (`OleView.exe`) for that but wasn't able to get the interface definition.

---

I am trying to implement `IFileDialogPrivate` while doing some experiments on forcing `IExplorerBrowser` control to filter Windows 7 library folders. `IFileDialog` (which seems to use `IExplorerBrowser`) does it somehow and `IExplorerBrowser` askes service provider for `IFileDialog` and `IFileDialogPrivate` if `ICommDlgBrowser` is provided so I tryied to explore that interface. (Also it asks for few other interestingly named interface - could be useful).

Comment: It isn't available and no way to get it either.  The only reason you know about it is because its proxy is registered, allowing the debugger to dig the name out of the registry.  Reverse-engineering COM interfaces isn't possible.  Even if you managed to guess at the interface, it is guaranteed to break in the next Windows version.  Or the previous.  Don't go there.

Comment: Yes. I expected that using such interface will lead me to heavy dependence on environment. But since I already run out of ideas this became new goal on its own. A bit more research/learning/experimenting/playing than actually doing the task. I left the `IExplorerBrowser` until it will be able to filter properly.